# Determining conjugacy class of a subgroup from intersection with conjugacy classes

Tags: finite-groups, gr.group-theory

Is a subgroup of a finite group uniquely determined, up to conjugation, by the subset of conjugacy classes of the larger group that it intersects?

Comment: This is certainly true when the subgroup intersects every conjugacy class, and when it intersects only one conjugacy class. See this recent related question:
    http://mathoverflow.net/questions/26979/generating-a-finite-group-from-elements-in-each-conjugacy-class

Comment: The subgroups < (13)(24) > and < (13)(24), (12)(34) > in $S_4$ intersect the same conjugacy classes and aren't even isomorphic!

Comment: Is it uniquely determined by the sizes of its intersections with each conjugacy class?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $G$ be the group of affine linear maps over the Galois field $k=GF(16)$
of order $16$. The elements of $G$ are maps from $k$ to itself of the form
$x\mapsto ax+b$ where $a\in k^*$ and $b\in G$. Those with $a=1$ form
a normal elementary abelian subgroup~$H$. All nontrivial elements of $H$
are conjugate. Then $H$ contains lots of subgroups of order $4$, thirty-five
in all, each consisting of the identity and three elements of this conjugacy class
of involutions. But these are not all conjugate under $G$; it is clear that such a
subgroup has at most fifteen conjugates.

Comment: Thanks Robin! That's neat. Could you give me a presentation of that group so that I can play with this example myself?

Comment: If you really want a presentation: generators
$a$, $b$, $c$, $d$, $x$. Let $a^2=\cdots=d^2=x^{15}=1$,
$a,\ldots,d$ commute,
$xax^{-1}=b$, $xbx^{-1}=c$, $xcx^{-1}=d$, $xdx^{-1}=ab$.
